# Как указывать аргументы при инициализации класса, в котором указаны только аннотации типов?

Tags: python

Есть код

```
class Model(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)

class User(metaclass=Model):
    username: str
    password: str
    age: int

user1 = User('Alex', 'qwerty', 18)
```

Дальше следует ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    user1 = User('Alex', 'qwerty', 18)
TypeError: User() takes no arguments
```

Как заставить класс User принимать аргументы из аннотаций типов?

И есть ли возможность сделать мета-класс `Model` обычным классом и из него управлять дочерним классом? Под управлением я понимаю: получение названий атрибутов, их значений, названия класса.

Каким образом можно получить значение параметра в скобках класса?
Пример:

```
class Hero(Model, table=True):
    pass
```

Именно значение `table`.

Спасибо.

Comment: Я не большой знаток ООП, так что либо я ещё меньший его знаток, либо вопросы странно сформулированы. 1) Что такое "заставить класс User принимать аргументы из аннотаций типов"? а) Аннотация - информационное поле, откуда там аргументу взяться? б) В User надо нормальным образом передавать три параметра. Почему так не делаете?

Comment: я делаю простенькую ORM

Comment: просто если вы посмотрите на то как в SQLModel можно создать модель, то там мы наследуемся от базовой модели и дальше создаём экземпляры этой модели. И хотелось бы узнать как это реализовать

Comment: Я не посмотрю:-) (у вас даже метка sql не стоит, кстати). Оставлю отвечать на вопросы кому-то, кто знает и SQL и ООП хорошо, но я бы переформулировал вопрос на вашем месте, указав, что хотите иметь в результате.

Comment: @Сергей нормальный это вопрос. К sql не имеет отношения (такой функционал используется не только а ORM, а и например в [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/)). Вопрос по чистому питону.

Comment: Видимо, метакласс должен прочитать аннотации и сгенерировать для класса функцию `__init__` с нужными аргументами. Если задача сделать ORM, то наверное стоит покопаться в исходниках уже существующих ORM, как они это делают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все можно, это делается так:

```
class ModelMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, table=False, **kwargs):
        def init(self, *args):
            print(f"table={table}")
            for field, value in zip(namespace["__annotations__"], args):
                setattr(self, field, value)

        namespace["__init__"] = init
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)


class Model(metaclass=ModelMeta):
    pass


class User(Model, table=True):
    username: str
    password: str
    age: int


user1 = User("Alex", "qwerty", 18)

print(user1.username)
print(user1.password)
print(user1.age)
```

Comment: Почему не известен порядок?

Comment: В `namespace` они приходят как dict. Может и есть способ добыть, но я его не знаю (пока что, еще смотрю).

Comment: Начиная с Python 3.7, словари сохраняют порядок ключей

Comment: Не был уверен гарантируется ли, что в dict они попадут в правильном порядке. Сейчас нашел, что гарантируется https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444638/is-the-order-of-entries-in-class-annotations-consistent-with-their-definitio

Comment: Спасибо большое вам, всё так как я хотел. Теперь я всё понял!